# bash script local path dependancy?

Tags: bash

I created a script which refers to files in it's local directory

This seems to work fine when executed in the same directory but if done from somewhere else "`/home/user/script.sh`" then it breaks.

I tried including a variable which gets it's working path but still seems to have a problem. How can I fix this ?

```
path=`dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")"` ...
```

Comment: Mind sharing the script itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, include a `cd` statement that sets the current directory to where the files the script needs, resides. For example, if your files reside in a folder /home/user/Documents", then add following line in the script before the commands that actually expect to find the files:

```
cd "/home/user/Documents"
```

(Quotes are needed if the pathname would contain spaces or other special characters).

This could be

```
cd $path
```

if you manage to set the working directory through a variable. To make this work though the construct you are proposing, use command substitution, i.e. $(command). Then, the output of the command will be assigned to a string, that you in turn can assign to your variable, i.e. something like:

```
path=$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")") ...
```